# Обрезание фотографий при отображении.

Tags: html, javascript, html5, php

Здравствуйте.
Интересует казалось бы простой вопрос.
Есть прямоугольная фотография. Но на сайте под неё отведена квадратная форма
И если сделать например `<img width="250" height="250">` то мы получим сжатую по вертикали или горизонтали фотографию.
Как этого избежать?
Хотелось бы увидеть 2 реализации.
1.Что бы выбирался верхняя часть (при высокой фотографии) или левая (при широкой).
2.Что бы выбиралась центральная часть.
Гуглить не помогло.
Заранее спасибо !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

погуглите ещё на тему background-size. Поможет.

```
<div class="image" style="background-image: url(photo.jpeg)"></div>
```

и в css:

```
.image {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: center top no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Плохо [искали](https://www.google.ru/search?q=image+crop+css):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493296/css-display-an-image-resized-and-cropped
- http://www.squareonemd.co.uk/how-to-crop-an-image-with-a-css-class/
- http://designshack.net/articles/css/focal-point-intelligent-cropping-of-responsive-images/
- http://cssglobe.com/3-easy-and-fast-css-techniques-for-faux-image/

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте таким кодом 
     .img {
     display: inline-block;
        width: 150px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 15px;

```
  }
  .img img {
   width: 150px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

Только размеры и бакграунд под себя подстройте.